# Unable to cast object of type 'ASP.home_aspx' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton'

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

In my application i have two gridviews where in my first gridview i will just have the counts along with the username and on clicking the link button in first gridview i will get the complete information of that particular user in second gridview which is done the problem is in my second gridview i have paging on cliking the paging i will going to that link button event nad getting the below exception:

> Unable to cast object of type 'ASP.home_aspx' to type
>   'System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton'.

```
First Gridview

User                         Completed batches
nandini                            23
```

on clicking 23 in first gridview i will get the information of 23 records in second gridview with paging and on clicking that paging in second gridview i will first go to this method

```
protected void grd1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
string Eve1 = ViewState["SecondStatus"].ToString();
}
```

when i first click pagining in gridview i will come into above code and after that i will go to lnkCompleted1_Click event

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you simply try OnCommand instead of OnClick and do :

```
User1 = e.CommandArgument;
```

instead of

```
User1 = ((LinkButton)sender).CommandArgument;
```

You can find a simple example [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.commandargument(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: could you please share some sample code as i am new to this you want me to remove complete click event lnkCompleted1_Click

Comment: just put the code what you have currently written inside OnClick to OnCommand Event, and use e.CommandArgument to get the CommandArgument, and it will work fine.

Comment: then on calling command event in pageindexchangingevent of gridview in this way protected void grd1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
string Eve1 = ViewState["SecondStatus"].ToString();
if (Eve1 == "Completeddays")
  {
     lnkCompleted1_Command(this, new EventArgs());
  }
}                                                                                                                                
i am getting this error cannot convert from 'System.EventArgs' to 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.CommandEventArgs'

Comment: how can i call this link button event in my page index event             
protected void lnkCompleted1_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e) here on calling command event in pageindexchangingevent of gridview in this way protected void grd1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e) { string Eve1 = ViewState["SecondStatus"].ToString(); if (Eve1 == "Completeddays") { lnkCompleted1_Command(this, new EventArgs()); } } i am getting this error cannot convert from 'System.EventArgs' to 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.CommandEventArgs'

Answer (score 0):

You are expecting here:

```
User1 = ((LinkButton)sender).CommandArgument;
```

`sender` to be `LinkButton`. But you are calling this handler from another handler `grd1_PageIndexChanging` and there `sender` is just your page. This is why exception happens.

Better understand what `User1` should be in this special case and move the common code into separate function.

Comment: that user i nothing but user in first gridview                                                             First Gridview

User                         Completed batches
nandini                            23                                                                               on clicking 23 i will get second gridview with 23 records of nandini with paging when i click 2 nd page i will be going into paging event of second gridview and from there to finally lnkCompleted1_Click event there i am getting this exception

Answer (score 0):

it seems like you have a problem to this:

```
User1 = ((LinkButton)sender).CommandArgument;
```

Your `sender` is an object that holding to a `Linkbutton`.

Now I have a question `How about your User1, is it a Linkbutton?`

if not then it is your issue.

Comment: i had mentioned in my original post as first gridview there we have user and his/her corresponding completeddays records as 23 on clicking that 23 i will get all the 23 records in second gridview with paging